# Proper return statement and function type

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc, typedef, function-declaration

I am experimenting with malloc and I am trying to create a dynamic 2D array, I know the size of the **second dimension** and I am allocating memory like so:

```
int (*arr)[SIZE] = NULL;
arr = malloc(sizeof(arr[SIZE]) * 10);
```

My question is, is it possible place the above code into a function, and return the address of the allocated memory, if so what should the type be?

Edit: I am aware of the other method of allocating and return a pointer to a pointer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters the argument of malloc is confusing

```
arr = malloc(sizeof(arr[SIZE]) * 10);
```

It seems you mean

```
arr = malloc(sizeof( *arr ) * 10);
```

That is you are trying to allocate dynamically an array of the type `int[10][SIZE]`.

More precisely the record used as an argument in the call of malloc

```
arr = malloc(sizeof(arr[SIZE]) * 10);
```

is correct but very confusing.  It is better not to use such a record for the `sizeof` operator.

The function declaration can look like

```
int ( *allocation( size_t n ) )[SIZE];
```

Or you can introduce a typedef name like

```
typedef int ( *Array2D )[SIZE];
```

and then declare the function like

```
Array2D allocation( size_t n );
```

where `n` corresponds to the used by you value 10. That is using the parameter you can specify any number for the array dimension apart from 10.

Answer (score 2):

The allocation size `sizeof(arr[SIZE]) * 10` is incorrect but will evaluate to the expected size by coincidence. It should be `sizeof(*arr) * 10`, meaning 10 times the size of whatever `arr` points to, in this case arrays of `SIZE` `int`.

You can encapsulate this allocation in a function this way:

```
int (*allocate2D(size_t n))[SIZE] {
    int (*arr)[SIZE] = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * n);
    return arr;
}
```

Or better:

```
int (*allocate2D(size_t n))[SIZE] {
    return calloc(sizeof(int[SIZE]), n);
}
```